# Dealing with concurrent requests in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, session

Say I have created an online banking system using CodeIgniter/PHP and MySQL, and have the following to withdraw money from my bank account:

```
function withdraw($user_id, $amount) {
    $amount = (int)$amount;

    // make sure we have enough in the bank account
    $balance = $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id)
                        ->get('bank_account')->balance;
    if ($balance < $amount) {
        return false;
    }

    // take the money out of the bank
    $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id)
             ->set('balance', 'balance-'.$amount, false)
             ->update('bank_account');

    // put the money in the wallet
    $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id)
             ->set('balance', 'balance+'.$amount, false)
             ->update('wallet');

    return true;
}
```

First, we check to see if the user *can* perform the withdrawl, then we subtract from the account, and then we add to the wallet.

The problem is that I can send out multiple requests at pretty much the exact same time (this is basically trivial using `curl`). Each request gets its own thread, which all run concurrently. As such, each performs the check to see if I have enough in my bank (which I do), and then each performs the withdrawal. As a result, if I start a balance of 100, and I send out two `curl` requests which cause such a withdrawal of 100 at the same time, then I end up with 200 in my wallet and -100 in my bank account, which should not be possible.

What is the correct "CodeIgniter" way to solve this kind of TOCTOU vulnerability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd set the storage engine of the `bank_account` and `wallet` tables to [InnoDB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-storage-engine.html) which has transaction support and then include a [FOR UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) clause in the SELECT statement to lock the `bank_account` table for the duration of the transaction.

The code would then be something like the following.

```
function withdraw($user_id, $amount) {
    $amount = (int)$amount;

    $this->db->trans_start();

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM bank_account WHERE user_id = $user_id AND balance >= $amount FOR UPDATE");

    if($query->num_rows() === 0) {
        $this->db->trans_complete();
        return false;
    }

    $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id)
             ->set('balance', 'balance-'.$amount, false)
             ->update('bank_account');

    $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id)
             ->set('balance', 'balance+'.$amount, false)
             ->update('wallet');

    $this->db->trans_complete();

    return true;
}
```

Comment: According to the docs (http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/transactions.html), "they demand that you keep track of your queries and determine whether to commit or rollback based on the success or failure of your queries". So unless I am mistaken, this would have no effect becomes none of the commands fail.

Comment: You misread that sentence and skipped the next... "This is particularly cumbersome with nested queries. In contrast, we’ve implemented a smart transaction system that does all this for you automatically (you can also manage your transactions manually if you choose to, but there’s really no benefit)."

Comment: I think I am still not understanding. I am not concerned with failing queries and rolling back, but am concerned with the non-atomic nature of a check-then-withdraw. The CI docs I linked to in my previous comment say nothing about atomicity or locks. Does a transaction guarantee atomicity / handle locking / etc? How would it know which tables to lock?

Comment: According to InnoDB's docs, transactions are atomic and isolated, so I figured I'd just go ahead and test it: I converted both `bank_accont` and `wallet` to InnoDB and replaced my `lock tables` with `$this->db->trans_start()` and my `unlock tables` with `$this->db->trans_complete()`. I am now once again able to double-withdraw, so can confirm that the db is *not* treating the check and the withdrawal as an atomic operation.

Comment: @Mala, the FOR UPDATE in the SELECT statement I provided above is crucial.  The code I have above should perform a lock on the bank_account table.  I should have highlighted FOR UPDATE in my original answer so it was clearer.  Answer updated.  Did you include the FOR UPDATE clause in your test?

Comment: Oh! Thank you, I managed not to notice that at all. I'll try this again when I get the chance and report back :)

Answer (score 0):

What I was looking for was [table locking](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html).

To make this function safe, I need to lock the tables at the start of the function, and then release them at the end:

```
function withdraw($user_id, $amount) {
    $amount = (int)$amount;

    // lock the needed tables
    $this->db->query('lock tables bank_account write, wallet write');

    // make sure we have enough in the bank account
    $balance = $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id)
                        ->get('bank_account')->balance;
    if ($balance < $amount) {
        // release the locks
        $this->db->query('unlock tables');
        return false;
    }

    // take the money out of the bank
    $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id)
             ->set('balance', 'balance-'.$amount, false)
             ->update('bank_account');

    // put the money in the wallet
    $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id)
             ->set('balance', 'balance+'.$amount, false)
             ->update('wallet');

    // release the locks
    $this->db->query('unlock tables');

    return true;
}
```

This makes any attempt to write to said tables by any other MySQL connection hang until the lock has been released.

Comment: Is this your answer or question